# I am having this problem when I try to build the app in Xcode "Error: Type 'ImageDecoderCallback' not found."

Tags: flutter, build

I am new in Stackoverflow and not really sure how this works.

I have this problem with my Flutter app when I try to build it in XCode

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image_library-3.5.1/lib/src/extended_asset_bundle_image_provider.dart:49:32: Error: Type 'ImageDecoderCallback' not found.

Is there anyone that can help me?

Regards

I did some researches and found that the issue is with "extended_image_library" package but even when I removed it again got same issue.